# Angular 2 outlets side by side

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

How do I render components side by side using route-outlets?
For what I understand using auxiliary outlets will not solve my problem as all my views/routes are connected and should be opened in a specific order.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

PrimaryTemplate:

```
<h1>PrimaryView</h1>
<div class="col-lg-6"> <!-- using bootstrap -->
    <first-level-child [firstId]="firstIdFromRouterParam"></first-level-child>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-6"> 
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

PrimaryComponent:

```
@RouteConfig([
    { path: 'first/:firstId/second/:secondId', name: 'SecondLevelChild', component: SecondLevelChildComp}
])
```

You can find discussions on this topic at the bottom of this issue: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/6204

Comment: I want support for an arbitrary number of nested views, not just two. For what I understand your code will only allow two levels?

Comment: You are right. Didn't see that requirement in your question. But this whole topic seems to be a problem with angular2 as seen in the issue I posted. I also didn't find the perfect solution yet.